# Is it bad practice to expose user data through url

Tags: rest

Is it bad that I put users' current coordinates in url and access it in my REST service? should I change the operation from GET to POST to make the request invisible?

Answer (score 0):

you can use get and you can add that information in HTTP Headers, you should also encrypt sensitive information.